# Issues with misconfigured Apache vhosts

Tags: configuration, debian, apache2, vhosts

I have issues with setup correct vhosts in Apache.
simlink ln -s /mnt/d/localdevelopment /var/www/localdevelopment

In mysite.local.conf

DocumentRoot /var/www/localdevelopment/mysite

The issues is when I go to mysite.local I get the index of localdevelopment

If I navigate to the directory mysite is going to mysite.local/localdevelopment/mysite and is not working.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's turn out that is an Apache2 issue, is displayed only the default vhost, so i have disable the conf for localdevelopment and leave only vhost for mysite and is working. 
So until i found a solution, i have to disable and enable vhost to see the proper project.